# Mapping Categorical Data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do mapping of cat variable separately in pandas,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Users': ['123', '456', '789', '159', '789', '123', '159']})
df.Users.astype("category").cat.codes

Out[25]: 
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    3
5    0
6    1
dtype: int8
```

I need to pass the Users separately to have a record of the labels to match categories. so I tried

```
Users_types = ['123', '456', '789', '159']
df.Users.astype("category", categories=Users_types).cat.codes
```

But I am getting error

```
"Got an unexpected argument: {}".format(deprecated_arg)
ValueError: Got an unexpected argument: categories
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution is specify [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#controlling-behavior):

```
Users_types = ['123', '456', '789', '159']

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
s = df.Users.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories=Users_types)).cat.codes

print (s)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    2
5    0
6    3
dtype: int8
```

Or use [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
Users_types = ['123', '456', '789', '159']
s = pd.Categorical(df.Users, categories=Users_types).codes
print (s)
[0 1 2 3 2 0 3]
```